# How is recursion working within this method?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary

I am writing a method to find if a binary tree is full or not, here is what I have so far:

```
    public boolean full(){
    return fullHelper(this);
}

public boolean fullHelper(BinaryTreeNode<T> node){
    if (node == null){return false;}
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null){return true;}
    if (node.left != null && node.right != null){
        return fullHelper(node);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The node you pass in can be the root or some arbitrary node that will check if the sub tree is full. My method keeps getting stuck on the line

```
return fullHelper(node);
```

I was wondering why it will not pass through the line above it to check if both of the children are null. I am fairly new to both Binary Trees and recursion in general so if anyone could help explain any wrong assumptions I made it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean that it "gets stuck"?

Comment: You're calling the recursive method on the same `BinaryTreeNode`, so it'll never progress and eventually throw a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Im getting a stack overflow error. Also how would I go about traversing the tree?

Comment: I think the code is wrong otherwise too. It will return true for any tree as long as a node does not have exactly one child.

Comment: I added a height method that makes sure the height of each child is the same as well, but good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `return fullHelper(node);` your are reprocessing the same node you started the method with. Assuming both `node.left` and `node.right` are set this will result in an infinite recursive call and a `StackOverflowException`.

You need to progress the recursion to the left and right sub-nodes to check them the same way you just checked current node, e.g. you can replace the problematic line with:

```
return fullHelper(node.right) && fullHelper(node.left);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! As a follow up question, using node.right and node.left will allow you to traverse through trees, correct? I understand that using just node will continue to call the same node but using .left and .right will keep going to the children nodes as long as they exist?

Comment: With your current `if (node.left != null && node.right != null)` statements yes, both `right` and `left` will be checked when they are not null.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is iterate into the sub-nodes with the recursive call. For example:

```
if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
    return fullHelper(node.left) && fullHelper(node.right);
}
```

Comment: What @karol said :)